# Detect paired iPhone using ExternalAccessory framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, eaaccessory

I want to identify if I am currently connected to my paired iPhone device. I need to check it at a regular interval (say 5 seconds). I am currently using ExternalAccessory framework to identify it, but the implemented code does not provide me the list of paired iPhone.

Code that I have implemented

```
- (EASession *)openSessionForProtocol:(NSString *)protocolString
{
    NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]
                            connectedAccessories];
    EAAccessory *accessory = nil;
    EASession *session = nil;

    for (EAAccessory *obj in accessories)
    {
        if ([[obj protocolStrings] containsObject:protocolString])
        {
            accessory = obj;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (accessory)
    {
        session = [[EASession alloc] initWithAccessory:accessory
                                           forProtocol:protocolString];
        if (session)
        {
            [[session inputStream] setDelegate:self];
            [[session inputStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                             forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [[session inputStream] open];
            [[session outputStream] setDelegate:self];
            [[session outputStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                              forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [[session outputStream] open];
        }
    }

    return session;
}
```

The  NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]
                                connectedAccessories];  returns me 0 devices.
I am afraid if this method returns paired bluetooth devices or not.

**My requirement**
As mentioned above, I want to identify if I am currently connected to my paired iPhone device. You can suggest me alternatives to implement the requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

iOS devices pair with each other using Bluetooth 4.0 ([BLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy)) which is accessed using the [CoreBluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html). Apple's docs are pretty good for this technology and take you through the connection process as either a Central or Peripheral device.

External Accessory, on the other hand, is used to communicate with devices using older versions of Bluetooth, e.g. Bluetooth 2.0. It is an older framework and is more prone to errors that can be hard to overcome. Also, submitting an App that uses BLE is easy, whereas Apple are quite wary of Apps that use older version of Bluetooth due to device battery consumption (hence the LE (Low Energy) part of BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)).

Using the Core Bluetooth with Apple's documentation it should be quite easy to identify connected iOS devices and communicate with them.

Comment: If you specifically need to connect to a device that only supports the ExternalAccessory protocol as the OP seems to state, your answer does not help.

Comment: So this whas a while ago!! However, reading through the question I dont see where OP says that the device only supports external accessory. They are *currently* using ExternalAccessory and basically I point them to CoreBluetooth. What is the problem?

Comment: Well the title states: Detect paired iPhone using ExternalAccessory framework?

Comment: If there is a better framework, the title of the question should not prevent us from directing people to it. I find that sort of attitude frustrating for no real gain.

Comment: If I'm working with mFi devices that only work through ExternalAccessory, checking CoreBluetooth is useless and misleading.

Comment: Ok @JuanNunez I understand that you need External accessory. Do note in that OP says in his above question: `You can suggest me alternatives to implement the requirement`. Which is what I did.